# Is registering / unregistering to a .NET event a constant time operation?

Tags: .net, events, list, immutability, invocation

Initially, I had assumed yes, because I understood that the invocation list for a multi-cast delegate is implemented as a linked list, which supports constant time insertion and deletion. However, since multicast delegates are immutable, it seems that any add/remove operation would actually require the invocation list to be copied.  Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Cost of registering / unregistering is of interest because I have a long-running application that frequently registers handlers for various short-lived objects to an event, and then un-registers them just before they are disposed. The invocation list can get fairly long, so I really want this to be a constant time operation.

Comment: Adding is amortized O(1), exact same logic as List<>.Add().  Removing is O(n).  You cannot change this.

Comment: Unless you have 20 or more handlers attached, I would not be worried. I would get more worried about having 20 handlers  :)

Comment: @Hans, thanks. So it isn't a linked list. I don't remember where I saw that it was, but I've seen it a number of times in "official" sources.

Comment: No, it is an array.  Just like List<>.  Have a look-see with Reflector or ILSpy.

Comment: @Hans - Your comments are the answer to my question, so you might want to repost as such.

Comment: Please feel free to put the salient points in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Has Passant comment Aug 22 '11 at 21:31

Adding is amortized O(1), exact same logic as List<>.Add(). Removing is O(n). You cannot change this.

Answer (score 2):

> The invocation list can get fairly long, so I really want this to be a constant time operation.

How long is "fairly" long? Unless you're talking about *thousands* of subscribers, it's unlikely to be a significant period of time.

Spin up a test project and give it a go - an actual measurement trumps any number of wise old men (or women).

**Update**

One thought: If your specific case is for when the objects are disposed, try something like this:

```
public event PropertyChanged
{
    add { mPropertyChanged += value; }
    remove { mPropertyChanged -= value; }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    mPropertyChanged = null;
}
```

In your `Dispose` method, you can discard all subscriptions in one hit by just removing your reference to the stored event. This will undoubtedly be faster than unsubscribing one by one.

Yes, you're abandoning the multicast delegate to the garbage collector, but you're doing that anyway when you unsubscribe - once per unsubscription, in fact.

Comment: You're right about measurement being the only way to get a truly accurate reading. However, I am doing this in a critical section, was trying to avoid anything that isn't constant time. Initially I created my own (linked) invocation list, and did the callbacks myself. But it seemed like re-inventing the wheel, so I re-wrote to use an event instead. Creation/disposal of individual objects occurs at many different times before the event goes out of scope, so I can't set the multicast delegate to null. Or maybe I misunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: Rereading your question, I wonder if I've misunderstood ... I thought you had a single object whose event would have many many subscribers. When you come to dispose of that single object, you can just discard the subscriptions, no need to individually unsubscribe. If you instead have one object that subscribes to the events of many other objects, then you can use the same approach, but the gains won't be so large.

Comment: Actually, I a have a single object whose _private_ event has many subscribers which are objects created by the event-owner, and runs each on a separate thread. That's not a typical scenario, so probably some confusion there. The event owner can (and does) create it's own data structure to track the objects it creates, so I can just iterate over all the objects to communicate with them. I used an event because that I felt like I was reinventing / rewriting stuff that the Framework already provides.

Comment: +1 You have given sound advice, but the answer to my question is actually in the comments by @Hans. Thanks.